# openoffice calc: sum of a function of elements of a row

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

If I want to sum the elements of the first row (from the column `a` to `x`) of a calc document I can use `=sum(a1:x1)`.

My question is about the possibility to calculate something like this 
`=sum(a1^2/(1+a1):x1^2/(1+x1))` (of course this causes an error).

I mean to obtain the sum

`a1^2/(1+a1)+b1^2/(1+b1)+...+x1^2/(1+x1)`

Answer (score 2):

type `A1:X1` in cell A3 - press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
type `=INDIRECT($A$3)^2/(INDIRECT($A$3)+1)` in A4 - press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
type `=SUM(INDIRECT($A$3))` in cell B3 - press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

*Note that to change A4's content you need to select **A4 and then the entire range** first! Just clicking on A4 won't work.*

To change A3's content - to adjust for any change of the range:
1. Select the entire range starting in A4
2. Edit A4 and make sure to COPY the content.
3. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit editing
4. Press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to erase the array formula
5. Change A3
6. Re-enter the copied formula in A4, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

*This procedure is necessary in LibreOffice at least.

**Excel** does all this in a slightly different manner.*

Comment: In OpenOffice on a Windows computer the key combination for an array formula is Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: The above is tested in Libreoffice on Ubuntu 14.04... in Excel (Windows) it the array formula entry is done by CTRL+ENTER

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice Calc the following works; since the two programs are mostly the same, it should work in OpenOffice Calc, too. Use the formula 
`=SUM(A1:X1^2/(1+A1:X1))`; then hit CTRL + Shift + Enter to make it an array formula.

In general, a formula that takes single values and returns a single value (e.g., `=A1 + B1` and hit Enter) can be made to take and return a range by making it an array formula (e.g., formula is `=A1:A3 + B1:B3` and hit Ctrl + Shift + Enter). In this example, the formula will return three values, A1+B1, A2+B2, and A3+B3. (If you type this in directly in cell C1, the program will also fill cells C2 and C3.) Rather than displaying those values directly on the spreadsheet, you can, as in the question, pass those values to SUM or any other function that accepts a range of values (`=SUM(A1 + B1)` and hit CTRL + Shift + Enter).

EDIT:
With the mathematical function *f*(x)=*x*<sup>2</sup>/(1+*x*) from your question, in Calc you can replace *x* either with a single cell (e.g., A1) in a regular formula, producing a single value, or with a range (e.g. A1:X1), producing one value for each value in the range. In your formula, you just replace the single cell with a range (`A1:X1^2` etc. instead of `A1^2` etc.) and hit CTRL + Shift + Enter to make it an array formula.

Technical info on how this works under the hood: `A1:X1` in the formula is evaluated as the list (or array, hence the name *array formula*) `{A1, B1, ..., X1}`. `A1:X1^2` produces  the list `{A1^2, B1^2, ..., X1^2}`. Since `A1:X1` is in the formula twice, there are two lists; when the division is evaluated, `{A1^2, B1^2, ..., X1^2}/{1+A1, 1+B1, ..., 1+X1}` becomes {A1^2/(1+A1), B1^2/(1+B1), ..., X1^2/(1+X1)}. This list is what SUM sums.

Comment: Many thanks, it works. But I do not understand the syntax of `=SUM(A1:X1^2/(1+A1:X1))`. Here the function is `x^2/(1+x)`. If I have another function like `(x+4+2*x^7)/(1+x^2-7*x+)` what is the correct syntax.

Comment: @Name: I edited the answer; I hope this clarifies the general idea. For your second example, just replace the variable x with the range instead of with a sigle cell.